# can we print socket.getfqdn and socket.gethostbyname's output altogether in python

Tags: python, sockets

can we print both the info from "socket.gethostbyname" and "socket.getfqdn" in one line or altogether.. I have the below code working.. Just need to add on this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import socket
#Name = socket.gethostbyname(host.strip())
#IPD = socket.getfqdn(host.strip())

with open("/home/karn/host1.txt", 'rw') as f:
#     print socket.gethostbyname(host.rstrip())  socket.getfqdn(host.strip())
  for host in f:
     print socket.gethostbyname(host.rstrip())
```

What is expected is:

```
Server_Name             IP_Address
------------------------------------
server2.example.com         192.10.1.1
server2.example.com         192.10.1.2
```

Currently When i run it it only returns IP address as i am able to put "socket.gethostbyname" only  which returns ...

```
192.10.1.1
192.10.1.2
192.10.1.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) and slicing together, for example:

```
print("{0[0]}\t{0[2][0]}".format(socket.gethostbyname_ex(host.rstrip())))
```

will print

```
server2.example.com   192.10.1.1
server2.example.com   192.10.1.2
```

Comment: this is nice trcik , i used the "socket.gethostbyname_ex" just to expand & fetch the complete details as it returns with hostname , hosts conical name with IP address as well. but looks like you have trim is down.
Can you please explain the initial prefix of code `{0[0]}\t{0[2][0]}".format`.
Some where around the Serever name those are 48 Char long too , so if i can understand the formatting then will adjust the formatting, i am just a learner and trying to get from you experts.

Comment: `{0[2][0]}` format specifier selects the first (0) format argument, then gets the third (2) element of that list and (since the result is a list again) selects the first (second 0) element from that list.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful

> python -c "import socket; print socket.getfqdn(); print socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())"